# MySQL using an anti-join to select non duplicate values between two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to select values from table A based on values from table B. But, I can't figure out what to use.

Goal:

- A user on my website gets a whole list of check-boxes from table A on a web-page.
- Then the user chooses a check-box and the value from the check-box is
  inserted into table B.
- At some point in time, the user returns to that web-page and only sees the checkboxes that weren't inserted into table B.

In database terms, I would use a select query that compares table A (which holds ALL of the values) and table B (which basically stores a copy of a value from table A).

Here's my query. **wp_ml_skill_class** is table A and **wp_ml_character_skill** is table B

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.skill_name, s.skill_id, c.char_id, c.um_id, c.class_id
FROM
`wp_ml_skill_class` sc
JOIN
`wp_ml_skill` s 
ON 
(s.skill_id = sc.skill_id)
JOIN 
`wp_ml_character` c
WHERE 
c.class_id = 3 
AND 
c.char_id = 5
AND
sc.skill_id 
NOT IN 
(SELECT cs.skill_id FROM wp_ml_character_skill cs);
```

Comment: What is the common field between `wp_ml_skill_class` and `wp_ml_character_skill`? is it called `skill_id` in both?

Comment: Oh, thanks I am missing the FROM clause in my sub query. And yes skill_id is the same name for both tables.

Comment: You also seem to be missing an ON clause for the `JOIN` to `wp_ml_character`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a `LEFT JOIN` between table A & B, checking for `NULL` results from table B, which will represent the rows in table A which are not in table B.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM wp_ml_skill_class A
LEFT JOIN wp_ml_character_skill B
ON B.skill_id = A.skill_id
WHERE B.skill_id IS NULL
```

Here's a small example to demonstrate:

```
create table A (id int, val varchar(10));
create table B (id int, val varchar(10));

insert into A values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
insert into B values (2, 'b');

SELECT *
FROM  A
LEFT JOIN  B
ON B.id = A.id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id  val     id      val
1   a       (null)  (null)
3   c       (null)  (null)
```

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying. Basically, the null values in table B would act as placeholders?

Comment: No, the `NULL` is a behaviour of the `LEFT JOIN` where there are no matches on the `B` join criteria.

Comment: Yeah, the values from B are all NULL when the value from A is not present in B (because there are no corresponding values in B). So they do in effect act as placeholders. See the little demo I added to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thank you both.